# Отличие семантики от лексического значения

Tags: семантика

Чем отличаются понятия "лексическое значение" и "семантика"? Ведь и то и другое направлено на выявление содержания (значения и смысла) слова.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если речь идёт о семантике слова и лексическом значении слова, то семантика - более широкое понятие.

Лексическое значение слова - соотнесенность звуковой оболочки слова с соответствующими предметами или явлениями объективной действительности. Лексическое значение включает в себя не всю совокупность признаков, присущих какому-либо предмету, явлению, действию и т. д., а только наиболее существенные, помогающие отличить один предмет от другого.

Сема́нтика (от др.-греч. σημαντικός — обозначающий) —  круг значений слова и некоторого класса языковых единиц (например, «семантика глаголов движения»). https://zna4enie.ru/slova/semanticheskoe-znachenie-slova.html

Центральными понятиями в лексической семантике являются **лексические связи** и то, насколько значение отдельного слова определяется значением предложения в целом, которое называется в таком случае семантической сетью. Также обращают внимание на **отношения значений разных слов**. Центральными являются понятия **синонимия, антонимия, гиперонимия, гипонимия,** а также знаменательные и служебные слова. Важную роль играют также омонимы и паронимы, но они связаны как с внешней формой (написанием) слов, так и с их значением.

Когда мы делаем семантический анализ слова, мы указываем, однозначное оно или многозначное; определяем его лексические значения с указанием, какое из них прямое, какое переносное; приводим примеры включения слова в предложение, примеры фразеологизмов с этим словом; имеющиеся синонимы, антонимы, омонимы, гиперонимы, гипонимы, т.е. все сведения о слове, касающиеся его смысла, содержания.

Answer (score 1):

Семантика вообще-то раздел лингвистики. Если же семантика слова, то это синоним лексического значения.